# why remote powershell session dose not need password

Tags: powershell, remote-access, windows-authentication, powershell-4.0

why remote PowerShell session dose not need username and password?
this is very terrible because I feel anybody can connect remotely to my server.

I use negotiate authentication method and server machine is in domain and client machine is in outside the domain.

I use PowerShell version 4 and allow uncrypted traffic.

At first I connect VPN then with Enter-PSSession connect remote to server machine.

Comment: Your VPN required authentication.  At that point you already authenticated.  You wouldn't be able to connect if you didn't connected to the VPN first.

Comment: Thanks for response, but very similar tools like remote desktop need authentication again and I can restrict who can connect VPN and who can use remote desktop separately. but remote PowerShell session does not required authentication and it is very dangerous.

Comment: How is the VPN configured? Do you authenticate with Active Directory, or a separate account? What accounts are authorized on the server - domain only, or do you also have local accounts? Really though, you're this worried about security and yet you "allow unencrypted traffic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PSSession will use the credentials of the currently loged on  user.

If you are going through Remote Access Server in 2012R2 or similar (assumption based on PowerShell 4 being the 2012R2 flavour) and connected at logon, it's most likely your domain credentials being used to establish the session.